# Table View - On Click If Statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

I have a table view that I need to react differently when a cell is clicked with string X in it vs string Y. X would take you to to X View (XViewController) and Y would take you to Y View (YViewController), etc etc. Where would be the best place to insert this if statement, and how would I make it transition to the correct view?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then you can access the cell in question to read the string and present the appropriate view controller.

For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.text isEqualToString:stringX]) {
        XViewController *xvc = [[XViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:xvc animated:YES];
        [xvc release];
    } else {
        YViewController *yvc = [[YViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:yvc animated:YES];
        [yvc release];
}
```

Then, in whichever viewController is pushed, you can dismiss it with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: and how would I present the appropriate view controller? Does interface builder have an option for this or would I have to write it manually?

Comment: @James: I recommend that you use `-presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Answer (score 2):

The method:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Is what where you would do this. You would then grab the cell from that index path:

`UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Finally, check the string. The code should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
  UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if([cell.text isEqualToString:X]){
    // load view X and push onto the view controller
  }
  else{
    // load view Y and push onto the view controller
  }
}
```

If you used Custom cells, just look at the custom property instead of .text.

You should really look here:

[Apple Navigation Controller Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It's really simple. Just alloc the new view controller, and push it onto the navigation controller:

```
NewViewController * newView = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
[newView release];
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. How would I push onto the next view controller?